# Is there any way to get MainWindow in custom control without using Application class?

Tags: wpf, window, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I have one custom control which is placed inside the WPF Window,is there any possibility to get that WPF Window in Custom control and hook some events on that Window? without using Application class(ex Application.Current.Mainwindow)

Comment: Why can't you use the `Application` class, or is it that you just don't want to get the `MainWindow`? There is another way to access any `Window`, but it also uses the `Application` class.

Comment: @Sheridan :Because we have used this control in Dyalog APL framework,so on that framework there is no application class so it throws exception on that.

Comment: Oh, that's a shame... I'll let you know if I can think of another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh... how about the `Window.GetWindow` method?:

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
}
```

Note that it won't work in the constructor, but if you use the `Loaded` event, it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks,will check and let you to know.